# Scraping Google Dictionary

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, user-agent, cheerio

I am trying to scrape Google dictionary and create an unofficial API. I tried to use cheerio and request package for Node.js to implement this functionality.

Here is my Code:

```
var cheerio = require("cheerio");
var request = require('request');

request({
    method: 'GET',
    url: 'https://www.google.co.in/search?q=define+love'
}, function(err, response, body) {

    if(err){
        return console.error(err)
    }


    var $ = cheerio.load(body);

    var a = $(".vk_ans span").text();
    console.log(a);

});
```

I initially tried to scrap this page "https://www.google.co.in/search?q=define+love", I tried to scrap the bold *love* written, it was written in a span which was in div with class `vk_ans`.

But when I `console.log` the answer, it results in an empty line, all other places I am doing same and Cheerio is working good.   What am I missing?

Comment: Solved the problem using accepted answer solution, and the dictionary API I made is hosted here, feel free to use http://dictionaryapi.herokuapp.com/.

Comment: It has been such a long time, now the API is hitting 50k hits daily, time flies.

Comment: API is hosted on https://dictionaryapi.dev, feel free to use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a user agent header in order not to be identified as a bot. 
Try this:

```
var cheerio = require("cheerio");
var request = require('request');

request({
  method: 'GET',
  url: 'https://www.google.co.in/search?q=define+love',
  headers: {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/63.0.3239.132 Safari/537.36"
  }
}, function(err, response, body) {

  if (err) {
    return console.error(err);
  }

  var $ = cheerio.load(body);

  var a = $(".mw").text();
  console.log(a);

});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked, though I have a doubt, when I tried to scarp of without the user agent header, I although could not scrap off the love definition and all that things, but the part where google says this much result has been found in this much seconds, I could scrap off, why so?

Comment: @SurajJain most likely because the dictionary data is the result of a Javascript request, and this data is rendered in the page only if the user agent is a browser.

Comment: @SurajJain You can check with Chrome for instance by changing the user agent to "Googlebot" (look on the Internet how to do that) and you will see that the dictionary content is not rendered.

Comment: Actually the dictionary is rendered though it is not the same, and has no css, and not all things are there, so that is why maybe I was not able to pick it, the div id and all are changed. Am I saying right?

Answer (score 1):

Also, you can use [Google Direct Answer Box API](https://serpapi.com/direct-answer-box-api) from SerpApi. SerpApi is a free API with 100 searches per month. If you need more searches, there are paid plans.

The difference is that all that needs to be done is to iterate over a ready-made, structured JSON instead of coding everything from scratch, figuring out how to bypass blocks from Google, and selecting correct selectors, which could sometimes be time-consuming. [Check out the playground](https://serpapi.com/playground?q=define+love&location=Austin%2C+Texas%2C+United+States&gl=us&hl=en).

Full code ([in the online IDE](https://replit.com/@MikhailZub/Google-Answer-Box-scrape-SerpApi#index.js)):

```js
const SerpApi = require("google-search-results-nodejs");
const search = new SerpApi.GoogleSearch(process.env.API_KEY); //your api key from serpapi.com

const searchString = "define love";                         // what we want to search

const params = {
  engine: "google",                                         // search engine
  q: searchString,                                          // search query
  google_domain: "google.com",                              // google domain of the search
  gl: "us",                                                 // parameter defines the country to use for the Google search
  hl: "en",                                                 // Parameter defines the language to use for the Google search
};

const getAnswerBoxData = ({ answer_box }) => {
  return answer_box.syllables;
};

const getJson = (params) => {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    search.json(params, resolve);
  });
};

getJson(params).then(getAnswerBoxData).then(console.log);
```

Output:

```json
love
```

Full definition SerpApi answer box output:

```json
{
   "type":"dictionary_results",
   "syllables":"love",
   "word_type":"noun",
   "definitions":[
      "an intense feeling of deep affection.",
      "a great interest and pleasure in something.",
      "feel deep affection for (someone).",
      "like or enjoy very much."
   ],
   "extras":[
      "deep affection",
      "fondness",
      "tenderness",
      "warmth",
      "intimacy",
      "attachment",
      "endearment",
      "devotion",
      "adoration",
      "doting",
      "idolization",
      "worship",
      "passion",
      "ardor",
      "desire",
      "lust",
      "yearning",
      "infatuation",
      "adulation",
      "besottedness",
      "compassion",
      "care",
      "caring",
      "regard",
      "solicitude",
      "concern",
      "friendliness",
      "friendship",
      "kindness",
      "charity",
      "goodwill",
      "sympathy",
      "kindliness",
      "altruism",
      "philanthropy",
      "unselfishness",
      "benevolence",
      "brotherliness",
      "sisterliness",
      "fellow feeling",
      "humanity",
      "relationship",
      "love affair",
      "affair",
      "romance",
      "liaison",
      "affair of the heart",
      "intrigue",
      "amour",
      "hatred",
      "liking",
      "weakness",
      "partiality",
      "bent",
      "leaning",
      "proclivity",
      "inclination",
      "disposition",
      "enjoyment",
      "appreciation",
      "soft spot",
      "taste",
      "delight",
      "relish",
      "passion",
      "zeal",
      "appetite",
      "zest",
      "enthusiasm",
      "keenness",
      "predilection",
      "penchant",
      "fondness",
      "be in love with",
      "be infatuated with",
      "be smitten with",
      "be besotted with",
      "be passionate about",
      "care very much for",
      "feel deep affection for",
      "hold very dear",
      "adore",
      "think the world of",
      "be devoted to",
      "dote on",
      "cherish",
      "worship",
      "idolize",
      "treasure",
      "prize",
      "be mad/crazy/nuts/wild about",
      "have a pash on",
      "carry a torch for",
      "be potty about",
      "hate",
      "loathe",
      "detest",
      "like very much",
      "delight in",
      "enjoy greatly",
      "have a passion for",
      "take great pleasure in",
      "derive great pleasure from",
      "have a great liking for",
      "be addicted to",
      "relish",
      "savor",
      "have a weakness for",
      "be partial to",
      "have a soft spot for",
      "have a taste for",
      "be taken with",
      "have a predilection for",
      "have a proclivity for",
      "have a penchant for",
      "get a kick from/out of",
      "have a thing about/for",
      "be mad for/about",
      "be crazy/nuts/wild about",
      "be hooked on",
      "get off on",
      "get a buzz from/out of",
      "be potty about",
      "go a bundle on"
   ]
}
```

> Disclaimer, I work for SerpApi